# ¿Como hago para que jupyter Notebook me devuelva los dos valores posibles de una raiz cuadrada?

Tags: jupyter

Estoy empezando con Jupyter notebook en la carrera, y en una practica necesito obtener los dos valores de una raiz cuadrada. Es decir, al poner sqrt(9) me devuelva 3 y -3. He buscado soluciones por todos lados pero ninguna me sirve! Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 0):

Una de las propiedades de la raíz cuadrada es que el resultado entregado es el valor absoluto de ambas raíces. Éste valor es el entregado por Python en Jupyter.

Aca tienes el detalle completo sobre la propiedad:
[image: Propiedades de la Raíz Cuadrada]
Tomado de: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%C3%ADz_cuadrada#Propiedades_generales

**Jupyter Notebook (Código Python):**

Si es realmente necesitas trabajar ambos valores, te envío esta función que te permitirá obtener un array con ambos resultados de la raíz:

```
import math

def sqrtTwoRoots(n):
    r = math.sqrt(n)
    return [[r],[-r]]

roots = sqrtTwoRoots(14)

for val in roots:
    print(val)
```

Aqui puedes ver el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos!